# How to catch "event" with socket Input/Output stream in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

Is there any possibility to communicate with clients by events? I mean:

I have connected client, `InputStreamReader` and `PrintWriter`

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        client.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
```

when I use `in.readLine()` server waits for incoming data. But i have this situation:

1. Client didn't send any data
2. Connection is still alive
3. I need to send some data to client (but `in.readLine()` is still hanging process) and wait for respond

The questions are: 
What is the best way to handle asynchronously incoming data? I mean something like "events". Should I create thread for read and another thread for write? If i can do it in one thread, could you give an example of the code please?
Is possible to abort waiting for `in.readLine()`?

Comment: You can check if any data is available by checking `BuferredReader#ready`. This method predicts if `read` is going to block or not.

Comment: Great, but in that case i can't avoid active waiting by `while(true)`

Comment: @sheldonCooper Is Scanner and BufferedReader the same (except waiting for variable type (int, etc..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java provides non-blocking i/o through the `java.nio` package ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)).  But Java's "nio" channels do not inter-operate with streams from `java.io`. So, if you want to use nio, you'll have to build your server with nio from the listener on down.

If you're stuck with the existing `java.io` streams, then you'll either have to use a thread-per-client model; or you'll need to devise a system for having a single thread (or pool of threads) manage a bunch of clients by looping over them repeatedly, polling [instream.available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) to figure out which ones have data ready to be handled.  Of course, in this latter case, you'd want to avoid busy-looping, so some appropriate use of Thread.sleep is probably also in-order.

Comment: thank you, with repeatedly pooling and sleeping it will be the easiest way.

Comment: On the other hand ... What about performance with 1000 clients, if there will be 1000 threads with 250ms loop?

Comment: @Tomasz there would *either* be one thread-per-client, in which case threads would block on the `read` operations, and there would be no looping/polling at all; *or* there would be a single thread monitoring a large number of clients in a polling loop, and possibly handing off active clients to a small thread pool whenever there is data ready for processing.  In any case, there would never be 1000 threads looping or polling anything.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion having a separate thread to perform socket IO is best if you want your program to behave asynchronously. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern.

For a simple application, what I'll do is create a separate thread to listen for incoming data, and register 'observers' or 'event listener' to this thread. When a data comes in, notify your observers so they can perform necessary actions.

While the listener thread is idle waiting for data, your main thread still can progress normally.

Make sure you're also familiar with Java concurrency programming

Comment: I'll try to make reader and writer as threads with shared variables ;)